# NPAPI drawPlugin retrieve cgContext from NPP instance

Tags: events, cgcontext, npapi

Im trying to draw a png in my (NPAPI)webplugin for Mac based on [basic-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/).

I would like to redraw the plugin on a `NPCocoaEventMouseDown` but I'm having trouwens to retrieve the `cgContextRef`.

The methode below works for the `NPCocoaEventDrawRect` but doesn't for the `NPCocoaEventMouseDown` because then I can't use `event->data.draw.context`. I tried to retrieve the `cgContextRef` with

```
    CGContextRef cgContext = (NP_CGContext*)currentInstance->window.window
```

but that didn't seem to work. Here's my function:

```
    void drawPlugin(NPP instance, NPCocoaEvent* event)
    {
        char* path = "/shot.png";
        if(!instance || !event)
            return;
        PluginInstance* currentInstance = (PluginInstance*)(instance->pdata);
        //CGContextRef cgContext = event->data.draw.context; //works with DrawRect
        CGContextRef cgContext = (NP_CGContext*)currentInstance->window.window;
        if (!cgContext) {
            return;
        }
        float windowWidth = currentInstance->window.width;
        float windowHeight = currentInstance->window.height;

        CGContextSaveGState(cgContext);
        //.....
        CGContextRestoreGState(cgContext);
    }
```

And the function is called here:

```
    int16_t NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance, void* event)
    {
      NPCocoaEvent* cocoaEvent = (NPCocoaEvent*)event;
      if (cocoaEvent && (cocoaEvent->type == NPCocoaEventDrawRect)) {
          return 1;
        }

      if(cocoaEvent)
      {
        switch (cocoaEvent->type) {
            case NPCocoaEventDrawRect:
                drawPlugin(instance, (NPCocoaEvent*)event);
                break;
            case NPCocoaEventMouseDown:
                drawPlugin(instance, (NPCocoaEvent*)event);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }  
          return 1;
      }
        return 0;
    }
```

How can I retrieve the `cgContextRef` in a `NPCocoaEventMouseDown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to redraw the plugin on a NPCocoaEventMouseDown
>
> How can I retrieve the cgContextRef in a NPCocoaEventMouseDown?

You can't do either of those things. You call NPN_InvalidateRect in your mouse-down handler, and wait to get a draw call-back.

> I tried to retrieve the cgContextRef with
>
> CGContextRef cgContext = (NP_CGContext*)currentInstance->window.window
>
> but that didn't seem to work.

Because that field is always NULL under the Cocoa event model, as documented in the Cocoa event spec. You are explicitly only provided a CGContextRef during a paint call, and it is only required to be valid for the duration of that call. (In case you are thinking of caching it for later use: don't. The results will be totally undefined behavior, probably won't work, certainly can't be relied on to work, and will almost certainly cause crashes at some point in some browser.)

Comment: In case you're wondering if smorgan is mistaken, he isn't. You are only intended to draw when instructed in any windowless plugin, and coregraphics on mac qualifies.  Even with the old Carbon implementation they didn't want you to draw just whenever, it just happened to work a bit better is all. FireBreath (http://firebreath.org) provides an excellent abstraction for this. You can, btw, request a draw event by calling NPN_InvalidateRect on the mousedown event.

Comment: Thanks smorgan and Taxilian. I'm new to developing a web plugin and sometimes the references and documentations are not completely clear to me so this answer really helps me out.

Comment: New-be question, where and how can I call NPN_InvalidateRect?